# How to Highlight a Selected Item in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I would like to simply show a border around the currently selected item in my LongListSelector. I have set an ItemTemplate for my LongListSelector, but I am unsure of how to modify the Border so that only the currently selected item contains a border.

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <!-- BorderBrush of all items are currently set to PhoneAccentBrush, need only currently selected item! -->
        <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3">
            <Viewbox Width="108" Height="108">
                <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="6,6" Width="108"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="delete" Click="deleteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

...

<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="0" 
                                    SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" 
                                    toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="108,108"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                                    />
```

Currently all of the items within the `LongListSelector` show the border. I would prefer to modify this in the code behind, but what I have thus far does not work

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void recent_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var item = sender  as LongListSelector
        item.BorderBrush = App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

When you access the selected item, you should access it as a `border` and not as a `LongListSelector` because that's how you show each item, while the `LongListSelector` is the container. You also forgot a semi-colon on the 3rd row, I've added it for you.

Your new code would be:

```
private void recent_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    var item = sender as Border;
    item.BorderBrush = App.Current
                          .Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have in fact tried that as well. I get an `AccessViolationException` on the last line

Comment: Additionally, I removed the `BorderBrush` property from the first line of the xaml `Border` tag `<Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3">` which set all of the items to a border color of `PhoneAccentBrush` by default (I just had this in there to test and make sure setting a border color worked).