# Stop a sound when a ListItem is "de-Selected"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I used this guide to make a customized longlistselector and play sound when an item is selected. 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-15-Playing-a-Sound-when-a-ListItem-is-Selected 
 and everything works.

Now I'm trying to find a way to stop the sound if the same item is tapped and it's still playing the sound, but can't find the right solution. Any ideas?

Thank you so much.

*EDIT*

Now it stops when click while is still playing. But it stops also if i click another element. Any advice? Please

```
private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{                
    LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;
    // verifying our sender is actually a LongListSelector
    if (selector == null)
        return;

    if (AudioPlayer.CurrentState == System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Playing)
    {
        AudioPlayer.Stop();
        selector.SelectedItem = null;
    }
    else
    {
        SoundData data = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;
        // verifying our sender is actually SoundData
        if (data == null)
            return;
        AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        // resetting selected so we can play the same sound over and over again
        selector.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have solved your problem, add answer to it (you can also answer your own questions) and then mark it as a solution (green tick). That answer then will disapper from unanswered.

Comment: No i've still a problem, now the sound stops when click while is playing. But i need to stop it only if I click the same item clicked before. Any idea? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code, you are just stopping it. It isn't hard, you only have to remember what you have clicked before:

```
private SounData selected = null;

private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;
   if (AudioPlayer.CurrentState == System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Playing &&
    ((SoundData)selector.SelectedItem == selected))
   {
     AudioPlayer.Stop();
     selector.SelectedItem = null;
   }
   else
   {
     SoundData data = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;
     // verifying our sender is actually SoundData
     if (data == null)
        return;
     AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
     // resetting selected so we can play the same sound over and over again
     selected = data;
     selector.SelectedItem = null;
   }
}
```

I think the rest you should be able to figure out.

Comment: Thank you! Really simple, just made something looks like your solution but used the private variable as a LongListselector and not like SoundData, and doesn't work!

Comment: Any ideas on how to change backgound color of the selected item until the sound is finished?

Comment: There are couple of ways to do it, search for https://www.google.pl/#q=highlight+selected+item+windows+phone, you will also find many answer on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470471/windows-phone-7-highlight-selected-listbox-item, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325889/how-to-highlight-a-selected-item-in-longlistselector